# displaying api information with different endpoints and render using flask

Tags: python, json, api, flask

greetings from argentina, I'm new in programming and I started a flask project, but i encounter a problem, I'm managed to display information from an api with one endpoint and render using flask, and for my next part I have to display information with several endpoints

This is the code I managed to render, looks ugly but it works

```
def home():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.date_posted.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=5)
    oficial = requests.get('https://api-dolar-argentina.herokuapp.com/api/dolaroficial')
    blue = requests.get('https://api-dolar-argentina.herokuapp.com/api/dolarblue')
    dataoficial = json.loads(oficial.content)
    datablue = json.loads(blue.content)
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts, data=dataoficial, datablue=datablue)
```

For my next page I have to do the same with multiples endpoint on the api, This is the script for reference of what I want

```
symbol = ['dolaroficial', 'dolarblue', 'contadoliqui', 'dolarpromedio', 'dolarturista','dolarbolsa']
for i in symbol:    
    api_url = f'https://api-dolar-argentina.herokuapp.com/api/{i}'
    data = requests.get(api_url).json()
    print(f' {i}: precio de venta', {data['venta']})
    print(f' {i}: precio de compra', {data['compra']})
```

I try to do something like this to see if I can loop through all endpoints ,but it wont render anything

```
def argentina():
    symbol = ['dolaroficial', 'dolarblue', 'contadoliqui', 'dolarpromedio', 'dolarturista', ' dolarbolsa']
    for i in symbol:
        api_url = f'https://api-dolar-argentina.herokuapp.com/api/{i}'
        datasa = requests.get(api_url)
        data = json.loads(datasa.content)

        return render_template('currency.html', data=data )


{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div>
    {% for dat in data %}
        {{ dat['compra'] }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

If I do it manually it will look very bad

Can someone show me the path to display it?
To anyone reading this thanks in advance and have a nice day

Comment: have you tried finding out what `datasa` is? like `print(datasa)` after getting the request back? maybe you need to use only `data = json.loads(datasa)`?

Comment: @Matiiss print(datasa) returns a 200 response and if I do data = json.loads(datasa) return an error: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response and doing datasa = requests.get(api_url).json() returns 5 dictionaries and this error:JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: ok, what type of data is `datasa.content`? (`print(type(datasa.content))`), perhaps, you may need to convert it to a `str`: `data = json.loads(str(datasa.content))`, also could you show the complete error traceback ([edit] it in the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra space in the last item of `symbol`, it's causing the API to respond with 404 status. `' dolarbolsa'` should be replace with `'dolarbolsa'`. That should fix the `JSONDecodeError` error (you need to find a way to handle errors in the API).

Then you will display only one price. That's because you are saving the dollar price in a variable instead of an array, and returning the template in the first run of the loop.

You should create a new array after `symbol`, fill it inside the loop, and then render it after the loop.

```
def argentina():
  symbol = ['dolaroficial', 'dolarblue', 'contadoliqui', 'dolarpromedio', 'dolarturista', 'dolarbolsa']
  data = []
  
  for i in symbol:
    api_url = f'https://api-dolar-argentina.herokuapp.com/api/{i}'

    datasa = requests.get(api_url)
    content = json.loads(datasa.content)

    data.append(content)

  return render_template('currency.html', data=data)
```